# RAID configuration file not present

Tags: linux, raid, suse

I am trying to configure RAID disks in my SUSE machine. I have 2 disks currently. I am trying to configure them as RAID using the below command.

```
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=stripe --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb6 /dev/sdc5
```

However, in [this](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup) link it is suggested that after using the mdadm command I have to edit the **/etc/mdadm.conf** file. But I do not have a mdadm.conf file currently.

My question is, will this file get generated automatically after I run the mdadm command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file isn't created automatically, but you can create it with `mdadm --detail --scan >/etc/mdadm.conf`.

The file isn't needed anymore as Linux software RAID improved since the document you linked to was written. Besides, the command above doesn't create as much information anymore as when it was written.

Nowadays you can have your `/` on a Linux software RAID too (all but `/boot`), so the RAID has to work before /etc is even available.

**Edit:**

As you described in [RAID mount not happening automatically](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99288/raid-mount-not-happening-automatically) it seems sometimes /etc/mdadm.conf is needed after all. Seems Linux software RAID only looks for RAID disks in certain places and your devices are not among them. My system runs fine without /etc/mdadm.conf as the RAID disks are normal SATA drives.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to resolve the issue as I had mentioned in the answer of that question.