# RAID mount not happening automatically

Tags: linux, raid

I've configured RAID array in my SUSE machine. Everything works just fine as expected. However, I need to mount the RAID array automatically when I boot my system. For this I added the mount point in `/etc/fstab` file. However, after rebooting, I need to do the below two steps.

```
mdadm -- assemble - scan
mount \dev\md0 \hana
```

It is not happening automatically as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to add the disks which are going to be in the array inside the /etc/mdadm.conf file. Now it is working as expected.

**EDIT**: The actual contents of the mdadm.conf file is as below.

Earlier I had only this entry inside the `/etc/mdadm.conf` file.

```
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=machine_name:0 UUID=XXXX:XXXX
```

However, I needed to mention which devices are actually in the array. So, I added the below entry inside the `/etc/mdadm.conf` file.

```
DEVICE /dev/fioa /dev/fiob
ARRAY /dev/md0 metadata=1.2 name=machine_name:0 UUID=XXXX:XXXX
```

Comment: Can you add the details to your answer? Otherwise it's not as useful as it could be to someone else that might pass by it while searching the site or google.

Comment: @slm, done sir! I edited the answer and posted it. Let me know if it is fine.